# How to get new logs in an EventLogEntyCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, event-log

I need to monitor security event logs on very busy domain controllers, which generate hundreds of them each minute.

I know how to use `EventLog`, `EventLogEntry` and `EvenLogEntryCollection` to open and read a server's event log, but an `EvenLogEntryCollection` can contain ~300.000 events, and it wraps around continuously (and very fast), so I can't rely on its index to find new entries.

So far, the only thing I was able to come up with is saving the timestamp of the last processed log entry and then iterate above the `EventLogEntryCollection` until I find an `EventLogEntry` which `TimeGenerated` properties is greater than the timestamp I saved; but it's ***terribly*** slow to iterate on ~300.000 entries to find the new ones.

How can I quickly find the new entries in an big event log?

---

### Edit:

I forgot to mention: I need to do this ***remotely***, not on the DC itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using Windows Management Instrumentation. WMI Query Language (WQL) allows you to specify your constraints. ManagementEventWatcher allows you to respond to WMI events.

Look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/wmi/archive/2009/12/28/using-within-in-a-wmi-event-query.aspx) for an example of the type of WQL query you need.

Here is how you code this:

```
WqlEventQuery wqlQuery = new WqlEventQuery(...);
ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(wqlQuery);
watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(_Your_Event_Handler_);
watcher.Start();

// Do stuff.

watcher.Stop();
```

Comment: Nice! Makes me wonder why there aren't event handlers in the EventLog and/or EventLogEntryCollection class...

Comment: My fault: there actually **is** an "EventWritten" event in the EventLog class which can be used for this purpose. But it only works on the local computer :-(

Comment: ...which takes me directly to the next question: does this WMI method work with remote systems, too?

Comment: I'm pretty sure WMI can be used to query information about a remote computer, but I'm not sure if this will work with events. Take a look at the constructor for ManagementScope. It takes a string of the form "\\computer_name\root\cimv2"